# DQN with prioritized experience replay and target network does not improve

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I tried to code a neural network to solve OpenAI's CartPole environment with Tensorflow and Keras. The network uses prioritized experience replay and a seperate target network which is updated every tenth episode. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque

from tensorflow import keras

class agent:
    def __init__(self,inputs,outputs,gamma):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = 1.0
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.999
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.outputs = outputs
        self.network = self._build_net()
        self.target_network = self._build_net()
        self.replay_memory = deque(maxlen=100000)

        self.target_network.set_weights(self.network.get_weights())

    def _build_net(self):
        model = keras.models.Sequential()

        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='relu',input_dim=self.inputs))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='relu'))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='relu'))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(self.outputs,activation='sigmoid'))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy')

        return model

    def act(self,state,testing=False):
        if not testing:
            if self.epsilon > np.random.rand():
                return np.random.randint(self.outputs)
            else:
                return np.argmax(self.network.predict(np.array([state])))

        else:
            return np.argmax(self.network.predict(np.array([state])))

    def remember(self,state,action,next_state,reward,win):
        self.replay_memory.append((state,action,next_state,reward,win))

    def get_batch(self):
        batch = []
        losses = []
        targets = []

        if len(self.replay_memory) >= 32:
            for state,action,next_state,reward,done in self.replay_memory:
                target_f = np.zeros([1,self.outputs])
                if done != False:
                    target = (reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.target_network.predict(np.array([next_state]))[0]))
                    target_f[0][action] = target

                targets.append(target_f)
                loss = np.mean(self.network.predict(np.array([state]))-target_f)**2
                losses.append(loss)

            indexes = np.argsort(losses)[:32]

            for indx in indexes:
                batch.append((self.replay_memory[indx][0], targets[indx]))

            return batch

    def replay(self,batch):
        for state,target in batch:
            self.network.fit(np.array([state]), target, epochs=1, verbose=0)
        self.epsilon = max(self.epsilon_min, self.epsilon*self.epsilon_decay)

    def update_target_network(self):
        self.target_network.set_weights(self.network.get_weights())

    def save(self):
        self.network.save_weights('./DQN.model')

    def load(self):
        self.network.load_weights('./DQN.model')

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
episodes = 1000
agent = agent(env.observation_space.shape[0],env.action_space.n,0.99)
rewards = []

state = env.reset()
for _ in range(500):
    action = agent.act(state,1.0)
    next_state, reward, win, _ = env.step(action)
    agent.remember(state,action,next_state,reward,win)
    state = next_state

    if win:
        state = env.reset()

for e in range(episodes):
    print('episode:',e+1)
    batch = agent.get_batch()
    state = env.reset()
    for t in range(400):
        action = agent.act(state)
        next_state, reward, win, _ = env.step(action)
        agent.remember(state,action,next_state,reward,win)
        state = next_state

        if win:
            break

        agent.replay(batch)

    print('score:',t)
    print('epsilon:',agent.epsilon)
    print('')

    if e%10 == 0:
        agent.update_target_network()
        agent.save()

    rewards.append(t)
    plt.plot(list(range(e+1)),rewards)
    plt.savefig('./reward.png')
```

The problem is that the agent gets worse as epsilon decreases. And when epsilon is a its lowest value, the agent only gets through 7-9 steps before the Pole falls, as seen in the Image below. Can someone tell me why my agent isn't learning anything and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your network output should be using **linear** as activation as opposed to **sigmoid**, since you are bootstrapping summation of all future rewards.  The loss should be changed to **mse** as well, according to the derivation for the td error from the original paper.

Also, if the experience ended in a terminal state (done==True), the td target for the action taken should set equal to the reward (you are currently setting it as 0).

Answer (score 0):

Try making the reward = -reward if done. It helps

Comment: Can you give an explanation regarding why it helps.

Comment: @SachinKumar It discourages loosing before the episode ends as it reduces it reward. It helps to reach the completion of training faster